# Win 8 App: Access Object from Resource in app.xaml from

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

How can I access an object thats defined in a resource in the app.xaml from a Viewmodel class?

Comment: Why would you want to access XAML resource from ViewModel? It's not supposed to.

Comment: I want to have access to the Bing Map object to center the Map because Map center can't be changed by a binding. see this post from me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203968/win-8-app-bing-maps-binding-location

Answer (score 0):

You can access resource like this:

```
var resource = App.Current.Resources["resourceKey"];
```

But I would suggest not to do that from ViewModel class because that's not MVVM suggests. You should not access any UI component from ViewModel.